# Differentiating answer of WH-query

Tags: nlp

Is there any known way of differentiating answer of wh-questions?

For example, I know this sentence: Omelette is stir fried egg

There are 2 possible questions, which have that answer: 1. WHAT is omelette? 2. HOW is omelette?

Human english speaker can easily guess that the question is the first one, because "NOUN is/are blablabla" is likely to be the answer of "WHAT is/are blablabla?" question.

On the other hand, if the sentence is the following: Omelette is delicious

Human english speaker still can easily guess that the question is the second one.

So, how can computer infer such thing?

Comment: So what do you want to do exactly ? Given a sentence, determine the WH-word (what, who, how, etc.) ?

Comment: The first question is, should we go with a rule-based approach or a machine learning approach? Do you have a corpus of sentences and their expected WH-word ? If yes, how many ?

Comment: Uh, actually I'm still sifting through existing (someone has written it in a paper, or better, someone has made use of it) techniques, so I haven't known whether to use rule based one or statistical one. I believe that sophisticated search engines (such as Google, Bing, Yahoo, etc) does more than dumb words matching. I believe they also at least do rudimentary semantic understanding. So I believe that someone has actually done something similar with what I want to achieve.